# Set select: false to subdocuments array at mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, subdocument

On mongoose there is a nice option to remove some fields from queries by default using the `select: false` option.

For Example:

```
var FileSchema = new Schema({
  filename: String,
  filesize: Number,
  base64Content: {type: String, select:false}
});

[...]

FileModel.find({}, function(err, docs) {
  // docs will give me an array of files without theirs content
});
```

Now, how can I use the same option to a field of subdocuments array?

(ie. in the following example, set `select: false` to the `comments` field)

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  user: ObjectId,
  content: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  comments: [{
    user: ObjectId,
    content: String,
    createdAt: Date
  }]
});

[...]

FileModel.find({}, function(err, docs) {
  // docs will give me an array of files without theirs content
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating a CommentSchema first,

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  user: ObjectId,
  content: String
  //whatever else
});
```

and then in your PostSchema specify

```
comments: { type: [CommentSchema], select:false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do this:

```
comments: { type: Array, default: [], select: false }
```

But you would be losing the declared structure underneath, otherwise what is really wrong with:

```
comments: [{
    user: { type: ObjectId, select: false },
    content: { type: String, select: false }
    createdAt: { type: Date, select: false }
}]
```

Which may seem a bit terse, but likely someone thought it was sensible.

Comment: The second option isn't useful in most cases. What will happens when you want to select the entire array? I guess you should select each field separately - that's a bad design..

Comment: Not as I interpret the docs. Yes it looks code ugly, but from a quick google search, you try to get the whole array with those settings, and the whole array will be omitted. Unless you explicitly ask for it.